# Send message to all processes

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm new to Elixir, I have a bunch of running processes and I need to broadcast a message to all of them from another process. After consulting the documentation for [Process](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#send/3) I still can't figure out how to achieve that.

It might not be the best comparison, but is there some function like "notifyAll" from Java ?

Comment: Do you want to send `info` messages? Synchronously? Asynchronously? Ensuring delivery? Peer-to-peer? Simple `PubSub`? Provide a link to `notifyAll` documentation if you want us to figure out your requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to make a mini game, I have a Necromancer which summons skeletons (each skeleton is represented by a spawned process `skProcess = spawn(SkeletonKnight, :battle, [skeletonKnightHp, skID])` and registered `Process.register(skProcess, :"Skeleton_#{skID}")` ). I also have a dragon process which has a _dragon breath_ skill that damages all skeletons, this one should send a message to all other skeletons with the type of message and the damage value (e.g. for sending a message to one skeleton: `send(:Skeleton_1, {:info, damage})`). The _dragon breath_ part is challenging for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach (described in comments) is vulnerable to atoms DDOS in the first place. 2M of skeletons would kill your *Erlang VM*, because atoms are not garbage collected. Also, spawning not monitored processes is not a good idea as stated in [`Kernel.spawn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#spawn/3).

Usually, you use [`DynamicSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#module-examples) to supervise children and it exposes [`which_children/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#which_children/1) that allows easy enumeration and sending messages to all of them.

Another approach would be to use [`:pg`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/pg.html) [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) module. Make your skeletons to join the process group and send messages to all the members.

One might also use [`Phoenix.PubSub`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#content) abstraction on top of `:pg` *or* [`Envio`](https://hexdocs.pm/envio/envio.html#content) to ease *PubSub* pattern implementation.

---

If you still want your initial approach with `spawn/3` to work, start the dedicated process that would keep track of all the skeletons (they might send it a “register-like” message upon start) and implement iteration through all the spawned skeletons within this process, sending all a message.

Comment: I'll go with the `DynamicSupervisor` approach, thank you !